# How to build kotlinx.coroutines in Kotlin/Native (test version 0.23.4-native-1)

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-native

This question is a continuation of this thread:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/246#issuecomment-407023156

I am trying to use `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:0.23.4-native-1` in a Kotlin/Native project targeting iOS.

#### `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin-native-dependencies" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:0.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-native'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        component {
            target 'ios_arm32', 'ios_arm64', 'ios_x64'
            outputKinds = [KLIBRARY]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    expectedBy project(':common')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:0.23.4-native-1"
}
```

The `kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native` dependency doesn't seem to work, as the produces build errors like:

```
error: unresolved reference: coroutines
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*
               ^
```

If I manually include the artifact dependencies such as `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native_release_ios_x64:0.10.3-native`, then I get a complier exception:

```
exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find "atomicfu-native"
```

This error persists, even if I also add `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu-native:0.10.3-native` dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of things to check for (I have been through this, and finally made it work) :

- Enable Gradle metadata. It's required to retrieve the coroutines dependencies. To do so, add this line in your "settings.gradle" file, after all the "include" instructions :

  ```
  enableFeaturePreview('GRADLE_METADATA')
  ```
- use gradle 4.7 (newer version are incompatible with the meta data of the current coroutines library, they require something with 0.4 version and the current published one uses 0.3)
- In the iOS module :

  ```
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:0.23.4-native-1"
  ```
- In your common module :

  ```
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.23.4"
  ```
- If you have a js module, it may fail due to the gradle metadata feature. You can fix it by adding this before each of your "repositories" blocks (https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/issues/301)

  ```
  repositories.whenObjectAdded {
      if (it instanceof IvyArtifactRepository) {
          metadataSources {
              artifact()
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Hope this will be enough !

Comment: Thanks @David, this helped. It turns out I also had to remove the `jcenter()` repository otherwise it still wouldn't work. Do you know what that is?

Comment: While you're here: It seems like the new Kotlin/Native plugin DSL doesn't support FRAMEWORK output, or interop with Swift/Obj-C. Do you know how I can use this   new DSL in parallel with the konan plugin to import an interop library, and then convert the build output to a Framework?

Comment: Hi,  outputKinds = [FRAMEWORK] works with kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:0.9-dev-2922

Comment: I've documented the process here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/native/README.md

Comment: I've performed the process described at the link above. The Android build happens successfully, but I don't know how to import the framework into xcode. Can someone help me?

Comment: I've created an example project with MPP structure, that uses coroutines:

https://github.com/thoutbeckers/kotlin-mpp-example

It describes how the Framework build is added as a custom shell script build step in XCode. The structure is mostly copied from the official example project mentioned in the README, but that project layout didn't work with dependencies (like coroutines) for me, so I made some changes.